# VOIP Mobile Apps Using Java Technologies

Tags: java, android, ios, sip, voip

I wanted to develop a VOIP mobile app that can make both local and international phone calls via wifi, data or regular lines. So my questions is What technology stacks are good to achieve the project? I personally prefer Java related solutions.Please walk me through the main business logic of such VOIP apps. Thank you

Comment: This isn't really a programming related question in my eyes. I feel you need to research more on Google. Regards.

Comment: This is simultaneously too broad, asking for product recommendations, and asking for opinions.